# Rigorously prove that $(A \setminus B) \cup A = A$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Rigorously prove that (A/B) U A = A

So I started off with

```
(x ∈ A ^ x ∉ B) v (x ∈ A)

Applying Distributivity

(x ∈ A v x ∈ A) ^ (x ∈ A v x ∉ B)

Applying Idempotency

(x ∈ A) ^ (x ∈ A v x ∉ B)
```

That's the point I reached, i.e. I'm stuck. I don't know how to break down further (x ∈ A v x ∉ B). Should I be using dominance or complement?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Maybe better to use "double inclusion" : (i) $x \in A$ then $x \in A \cup \text {whatever}$, Thus : $A \subseteq [A \cup (A \setminus B)]$.

Comment: (ii) if $x \in [A \cup (A \setminus B)]$ then either (ii-a) $x \in A$, or (ii-b) $x \in (A \setminus B)$. Thus ....

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that for any $x \in A$, we have $x \in C \cup A$ for any set $C$, so in particular, we have $x \in (A \setminus B) \cup A$. Thus, $A \subseteq (A \setminus B) \cup A$.

For the converse, for any $x \in (A \setminus B) \cup A$, either $x \in A$, or $x \in A \setminus B \subseteq A$, so in either case, $x \in A$. Thus, $(A \setminus B) \cup A \subseteq A$.

Combining the two, we have $(A \setminus B) \cup A = A$, as required.

Answer (score 0):

Your last line is equivalent to just $x \in A$ because if the first part ($x \in A$) is satisfied, the second part ($x \in A \text{ or } x \notin B$) is always satisfied as well, hence the second part can be removed.

Comment: Makes sense thanks, do you suggest any comment which should be writen when making such 'operation'?

Comment: Formally: $\left((x \in A) \text{ and } (x \in A \text{ or } x \notin B)\right)$ is true if and only if $x \in A$ and $(x \in A \text{ or } x \notin B)$ are both true. As $x \in A$ implies $(x \in A \text{ or } x \notin B)$, this is reduced to $x \in A$ being true.

Answer (score 0):

$A\setminus B$ and $A$ are both subsets of $A$ and consequently the union of these sets is also a subset of $A$.

So:$$(A\setminus B)\cup A\subseteq A\tag1$$

$A$ is a subset of $A$ hence also a subset of the union $(A\setminus B)\cup A$.

So:$$A\subseteq(A\setminus B)\cup A\tag2$$Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we are allowed to conclude that:$$(A\setminus B)\cup A= A$$